# Linq JSON filter

Tags: json, entity-framework, linq

I have a entity A

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now Description property contains JSON serialized DATA like :

```
{"Year":"2017","Quarter":"2"}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to filter on serialized data ?

Let's say I want all A where Description has value 2017 for Year, does linq permit such request ?

Now, Description does not always contains value as JSON. Is there a way to check if Description value is JSON ?

So the final code could look like

```
DbContext.Set<A>().Where(a => a.Description.Contains("JSON_REGEX") && a.Description.JsonFilter(d => d.Year == 2017));
```

When I record such DATA I use Newtonsoft.JSON.

EF 6.1.1

Comment: there is a Linq lib for JS. https://linqjs.codeplex.com/ It might provide you with an alternative way of Filtering JSON data.

Comment: I'm not sure this can help me, I'm working on server side here with C# only.

Comment: If it isnt too much of a change to do on the Front End, it might be an easier/faster alternative than trying to query JSON on the server

Comment: Ok. Actually it's not a matter of work. It's more I try to keep consistent with the architecture already in place. There should be no data processing after the model is send to the view.

Comment: I see. I will take a look around for a solution and see if I can come up with anything